# unable to create a document with raw content on dialog flow knowledge bases

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

i am using **com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.Document** to create document through java rpc,we have a setContent() method which is used creating document with raw content, when i try to create document i am getting below exception.

> Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: Operation
>   with name
>   "projects/agent-fa5be/operations/ks-add_document-NDQ0NDQ3MjI5MDA3NTIxMzgyNA"
>   failed with status = GrpcStatusCode{transportCode=INVALID_ARGUMENT}
>   and message = CSV documents must have exactly two columns. The
>   provided document has 1 columns.

when i check dialogflow.v2beta1 Documentation there clearly mentioned content is deprecated use raw_content instead of content. but there is no supported method for raw_content in com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.Document

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting a similar issue. I tried different libraries and techniques until I found something that worked. In my case I've to parse each row as follows:

```
let input = ['Question1', 'Answer1\n'];
let input2 = ['Question2', 'Answer2\n'];
let base64data = input.toString('base64') + input2.toString('base64');

const request = {
    parent: 'projects/PROJECT_ID/knowledgeBases/KNOWLEDGEBASE_ID',
    document: {
        knowledgeTypes: ['FAQ'],
        displayName: 'Echele',
        content: base64data,
        source: 'rawContent',
        mimeType: 'text/csv',
    },
};
```

This allowed my to submit the document, hope it works for you too!
Regards

Answer (score -1):

Please find working solution

```
String documentName="test.csv";
            try {
                byte[] bytedata = filedata.toString().getBytes();
                ByteString bytestring = ByteString.copyFrom(bytedata);
                byte[] bytedata1 = "text/csv".getBytes();
                ByteString mimestring = ByteString.copyFrom(bytedata1);
                DocumentsSettings docuemtnSettings = DocumentsSettings.newBuilder()
                        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();
                DocumentsClient documentsClient = DocumentsClient.create(docuemtnSettings);
                Document document = Document.newBuilder().setDisplayName(documentName).setContentBytes(bytestring)
                        .setMimeTypeBytes(mimestring).addKnowledgeTypes(KnowledgeType.FAQ).build();
                CreateDocumentRequest createDocumentRequest = CreateDocumentRequest.newBuilder().setDocument(document)
                        .setParent(knowledgeBaseName).build();
                OperationFuture<Document, KnowledgeOperationMetadata> response = documentsClient
                        .createDocumentAsync(createDocumentRequest);
                Document createdDocument = response.get();
                System.out.format(" - docuemnt created  ID: %s\n", createdDocument.getName());
```